# JDBC not connecting

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

While the build paths are not correct I obtain “com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver” from the stack trace. As they are built correctly, I obtain my printed statement “Successfully connected”. The JDBC is living within the getter/setters of the webservice as a method.

When I place the JDBC content in its own file with no builds and run as a java application I receive: “com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver”

When I place the JDBC content in its own file with builds and run as a java application I receive: “Successfully connected”

When the method is called from a test file as a java application I receive: “Successfully connected”
Ex:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            insert.main(args);
```

When the method is run as a java application on PO I receive: “Successfully connected”

When I place the method to be called under a setter (which will be invoked by the client, which will cause the jdbc to be invoked) I receive: “com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver”

Would you happen to have any tips for me? I’m clueless why it will work under being invoked as an application but not via client?

```
public class insert{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://00.00.00.00:0000/DB";
    // Database credentials
    final String USER = "usrname";
    final String PASS = "pw";

    try {   
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
       st = con.createStatement();

       System.out.println("successfully connected!");
    } catch (Exception err) {
       System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());
    }
    finally {
       try {
          con.close();
       } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
          try { 
             st.close(); 
          } catch (Exception e) { 
             /* ignored */ 
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Any tips at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you invoke this jar as a client?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I run the project on TOMCAT. I have a generated client which lets me have end user control to inputs via internet browser. The client is setting the information correctly. But the JDBC is shooting an error.

Comment: Again: how do you invoke this jar as a client? Do you execute something like `java jar yourJar.jar` or it is directly executed from Tomcat?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I right click the project on eclipse. Run As > Run on server. TomCat7. It starts the server. My client is accessed my a local-host url on a browser.

Comment: So you execute it directly from Tomcat...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That is correct. It is not executed as a jar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your jar misses the necessary libraries that provides `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` class and others to communicate with your SQL server. You have to make sure the library is loaded and available when is being executed from tomcat. Just copy your library and drop it inside `%TOMCAT_INSTALL%/lib` folder, where %TOMCAT_INSTALL% is the folder where your tomcat is installed, so the library will be available for every project (war, jar, etc) that runs in your tomcat installation.

Comment: I have copied over all of the files which are required which make it run individually over into the destination that you specified. I've rebooted the tomcat server, and am still obtaining the same error.

Comment: @Amasian21 then you're doing something else that's not posted that's causing the error. Because, sincerely, the only way to get that error is that the required libraries are missing in the classpath at runtime. Please review your project and check how are you calling this library.

Comment: Is there any further I can do differently? My stand alone jdbc build works, I took all of those files from the build and transferred to them to the TOMCAT lib. I then redirected the server on eclipse to point towards the one with the lib and run it. Same error appears.

Comment: @Amasian21 your specific problem is not about your standalone so forget about it. Focus on how you're executing the jar in tomcat. Provide the steps about how you're executing this method from your tomcat project.

Comment: I've listed how I did it. Now I've exported a war file and ran it under webapps of tomcat and receive "no suitable driver found for jdbc:~~~~//~~/~~." I attempted a runnable jar export with 'java -jar my.jar' and received a "failed to load main-class manifest attribute from my.jar"

Comment: The webservice itself works on Tomcat. JDBC works fine when ran as an appliction. Same jars added to Tomcat = still not working when ran on server.

Comment: It is very strange, indeed. Are you sure you have added your JDBC libraries in the lib folder of your tomcat installation? That should work. If not, then try adding in WEB-INF/lib folder of your web application next to all your third party libraries. If that doesn't make it work, then there's an extra problem that we cannot fix.

Comment: I am still obtaining the same issue after placing them in WEB-INF/lib. Same libs, works when ran as application. But not with Tomcat. I am clueless as of this point. I appreciate the help you've provided though @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @Amasian21 I'm as clueless as you, believe me. The only thing I can come up with is that you're deploying in the wrong environment, make sure you only have a single instance of tomcat or the application server you use. Stop it, deploy your application, delete temporary files, and restart your tomcat.